# implicit assignment of build->sourceDirectory in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

If a `pom` has a `<build>` tag but no `<sourceDirectory>` explicitly set within it, does Maven look whether there is a `src` directory with source code at the root?  I am asking this because some of the poms that I inherited in my project that do have source code do and some do not have `<sourceDirectory>`.  Is it necessary to explicitly set that value only if the actual source directory is something other than `src` (e.g. `src/java`)?

Here is a sample of the build definition from one such pom (note, this is a sub pom within the pom hierarchy):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Internal-Build-num>1.0-mybuild-SNAPSHOT</Internal-Build-num>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the `build` section in the `superpom`:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Version numbering -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- TAG format -->
                <tag>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</tag>
                <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Version numbering -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <updateDependencies>true</updateDependencies>
                <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven is about [Convention over Configuration](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-conventionConfiguration.html), so yes, you only need to specify `sourceDirectory` when it is other than default. Default location for java source code is: 
`src/main/java`

Read about default project configuration: [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: yes, `jar`.  if a pom has no `sourceDirectory`, it looks under `src`, that is where it finds `com` in `com.mydomain.MyClass`

Comment: This is very strange, default location for java code is always `src/main/java`. Maybe in this pom.xml is *special* plugin defined? I need more information.

Comment: yes, there are plugins.  i added a sample `build` section, please check it out

Comment: Ok, there is nothing interesting here. Please attach `build` section from **super pom** (parent pom). Or try invoking `help:effective-pom` from project, and take look into `build` section.

Comment: Still nothing here, maybe this `superpom` has parent defined? If not, please go to to project with `src` directory and generate `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: oh, never mind.  the poms that didn't have `sourceDirectory` set explicitly are indeed in `src/main/java` like you said.  my bad